# Creating a faceted search bar in oracle apex master detail page

Tags: sql, oracle, apex, master-detail, faceted-search

I'm trying to create a search bar in my master detail page that will allow my users to search for columns throughout my master and my detail tables (as the stock search bar only allows you to search for columns in the master table). Here is the code that apex generated for my search bar (tried to just add code inline here but it made the format look gross) [Stock Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6g0U.png).

I tried adding an exists condition that would test if one row returned, then it would evaluate as true. I then added my detail tables and a few test columns, and the sql validated fine. [Updated Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cl8y.png).

But whenever I run my application, I get this error I don't recognize [BIND VARIABLE DOES NOT EXIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf90x.png).

I've done some research and played around with the variables and the V() syntax that the error message suggests but nothing has worked. I've narrowed down the error to rows 24 - 25 so I'm pretty sure it's simply the wrong syntax for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this error by using a view for my "Master" table that contained all of the columns that my faceted search needed to be able to filter by. I completely took out my exists condition as it no longer was needed. [Faceted Search Query][4]